# Debug an error occuring when running an asp.net app first time

Tags: asp.net, global-asax

I am working on an asp.net application which errors only during the first time running the app. The error message is **{"Response is not available in this context."}** and the app breaks in the global.asax.cs page in Application_Error function.

The stack trace value is:    at System.Web.HttpApplication.get_Response()
   at pcMDnet.Global.Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\BuildDir\1.0.1.05\GIS\pcMDnet\Global.asax.cs:line 364
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()

How can I debug this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is due to a design change in the IIS7 Integrated pipeline that makes the request context unavailable in Application_Start event.

To solve it ether remove the reference on the content at that point, or make one time initialization on `Application_BeginRequest` where the content exist.

reference: http://mvolo.com/iis7-integrated-mode-request-is-not-available-in-this-context-exception-in-applicationstart

Comment: Thanks for the response @Aristos. What do you mean by "remove the reference on the content at that point"? What content are you talking about?

Comment: @DotNetRookie I mean that there is a call using the request context for some reason. If you can replace it by something else or totally remove it you are ok.